# events.js 167 error in React Installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux

I am trying to setup react in my PC. I have completed downloading the reacr modules and am starting to run through local server and these errors occur to me.

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mohin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-18T05_50_06_309Z-debug.log
```

I know it's simple error for local server and tried to open the index.html file manually then it didnot show the react logo but instead showed something like this.

Please help me through the installation.
[npm install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpf36.png)

[image]

Comment: Remove the node_modules directory and reinstall again using npm install

Comment: This might be helpful. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7061

Comment: @sv12 Do you mean delete entire node_modules file?

Comment: npm install gives me 302 warnings. Does this affect any how?

Comment: yes remove it and run npm install

Comment: Did it. But didn't work:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to inconsistency in npm versions I guess. I had deleted node modules and re-installed all the modules again using `npm-install`.

It worked fine from then.